# Why is an uninitialized class variable looked up in the global scope and not the enclosing scope?

Tags: python, function, class, variables

this is not a problem I need for a coding project, but a friend of mine sent this to me.
The question is: what gets printed out here? and why?

```
x = 0
y = 0
def f():
    x = 1
    y = 1
    class A:
        print(x,y)
        x = 2
f()
```

Output:

```
0 1
```

my first instinct told me that it should be "1 1", but I was wrong. I fiddled with the code and found out that if I remove the "x = 2" I would have been correct. but why?

also, it worked when I made the variables global. like this:

```
x = 0
y = 0
def f():
    global x
    global y
    x = 1
    y = 1
    class A:
        print(x,y)
        x = 2
f()
```

Output:

```
1 1
```

I am not looking for other solutions to the problem, just a better understanding of what is going on here.

thanks in advance

Comment: This is from [a tweet](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/1354305179244392453) by Guido van Rossum who got it from [kevmod's blog](https://blog.kevmod.com/2014/06/what-does-this-print-1/).

Comment: Too bad the link in the blog post to the original python-dev thread is dead (though it may refer to a thread on [PEP-227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/)).

Answer (score 10):

This is documented in the last paragraph of [Resolution of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names):

> Class definition blocks and arguments to exec() and eval() are special
> in the context of name resolution. A class definition is an executable
> statement that may use and define names. These references follow the
> normal rules for name resolution **with an exception that unbound local
> variables are looked up in the global namespace**. (emphasis mine)

So, `y` is looked up, as expected, in the nearest enclosing scope that defines it (the `f` function, where it gets the value 1).

On the other end, `x = 2` causes x to be considered local, and as it isn't already defined in `print(x,y)`, the exception causes it to be looked up in the global namespace (where it gets the value 0), instead of causing a `NameError`, as would be expected for an unbound local variable in a normal function.

---

I have long wondered why this special rule existed, and I just found the answer thanks to @orlp's comment under the question.

The code in the question seems to come from [this 2014 blog post from KMOD'S BLOG](https://blog.kevmod.com/2014/06/what-does-this-print-1/), and was recently [tweeted by Guido van Rossum](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/1354305179244392453).

And as someone asked about the reason why, [Guido answered](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/1354497377663557633):

> Backwards compatibility with Python 2.1.

So now we know...

Comment: Ugh, faster than me, +1.

Comment: @orlp Thanks, especially for the link to Guido's tweet that explains the reason for this rule!